# ERROR ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Tags: sql, oracle

Getting error :

```
ERROR ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
```

This is the code:

```
   select (select visano from employees where empno=empno) National_ID,basicsl Basic_sal,govt_cont GOV_CONT,pensnd Emp_PAID_CONT, (select max(to_date(pstyymm,'yyyymm')) from pen_ded where seril=seril) max ,(select min(to_date(pstyymm,'yyyymm')) from pen_ded where seril=seril) min,
    hsealwn H_ALWN,elcalwn E_ALWN,wtralwn WTR_ALWN 
    from pen_ded
```

Comment: `empno=empno` is true, by definition, so the first subquery will just return all the rows in the table. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to get only visano from first subquery

Comment: Just use proper JOINs in FROM and put CASE WHEN .. THEN where you need it.Many subqueries are hard to read and debug

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i resolve an ORA-01427 error (Single-row subquery returns more than one row)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420261/how-can-i-resolve-an-ora-01427-error-single-row-subquery-returns-more-than-one)

Answer (score 0):

This query is flawed in several places.
1) Selecting visano from employees should be performed as a join, and not as queried column. Is there a column connecting pen_ded with employees?
2) min and max columns should be queried with an analytical function, like so - Min(salary) Over (order by seril) min.

Other than that, all of the where clauses you wrote down are meaningless. I suggest going through a SQL tutorial to better understand the basic guidelines of writing queries.